# asp Button Created , Check it's Text after Action But text of thisButton return empty " "

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have created an asp button than on jquery load i have made a function to change it's text . On server click i have checked it's Text but the result was empty double quotation. While i can see the Text written on this asp button . 
Any help please? 
Thank you

Here are the codes below

front:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_User" CssClass=" btn btn-success offset-md-7 col-md-5" runat="server" 
                    onclick="btn_User_Click"/>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#<%=btn_User.ClientID%>").val('Add');
                $("#<%=btn_User.ClientID%>").text("Add");

});
```

// in DataTable I have changed the text of button onclick:doEdit

```
 "render":function(data){return "<a class='btn btn-info' onclick='doEditUser("+data.UserID+",\""+data.UserFullName+"\" , \""+ data.AccountDescription+"\" )'>Edit</a>" }
```

Jquery

```
 function doEditUser(UserID,UserFullName,AccountDescription)
    {
    $("#<%=hiddenUserID.ClientID %>").val(UserID);
    $("#<%=txtUserFullName.ClientID%>").val(UserFullName);
    $("#<%=txtAccountDescription.ClientID%>").val(AccountDescription);
    $("#<%=btn_User.ClientID %>").text="Update";
    $("#<%=btn_User.ClientID%>").val('Update');
    }
```

Back-end:

```
 protected void btn_User_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            UserFullName = txtUserFullName.Text;
            AccountDescription = txtAccountDescription.Text;

            if (btn_User.Text.Equals("Add"))
            {
                UserBO.del_AddNewUser(UserFullName,AccountDescription);
            }
            else if (btn_User.Text.Equals("Update"))
            {
                UserID = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenUserID.Value);
                UserBO.del_UpdateSelectedUser(UserID,UserFullName,AccountDescription);
                btn_User.Text = "Add";
            }
        }
```

Comment: `$("#<%=btn_User.ClientID %>").text("Update");` change to this one.

Comment: This is reminds me why some people hate this technology. It is so easy to write absolutely disgusting code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai I have tried every thing related to .text and .value but nothing worked

Comment: @aluan-haddad I think dataTable with jquery , ajax and json are faster than asp:gridView but not not easier

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easy : 
We just have to send a request to (Main page ) Mentioning the html element that we want it's value or text :

```
   string btnGroupText =Page.Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$btnGroup"].ToString();
```

Make sure to form your htlm ID in this way : **(ctl00)** + **(id)** of the parent form +**(id)** of your html element